# Creating ssh public key and copying using ssh-copy-id failing

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to setup an ssh public key configuration in order to mount an sftp share from my server onto my laptop via fstab. I have followed so many instructions and I believe I have done everything correctly yet the ssh-copy-id command keeps failing telling me that the id_rsa.pub file does not exist.

Here I create the key on my server:

```
(base) chuff@jan:~$ ssh-keygen  
Generating public/private rsa key pair.  
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/chuff/.ssh/id_rsa):   
/home/chuff/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.  
Overwrite (y/n)? y  
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):   
Enter same passphrase again:   
Your identification has been saved in /home/chuff/.ssh/id_rsa  
Your public key has been saved in /home/chuff/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

This is the contents of my ssh folder:

```
(base) chuff@jan:~/.ssh$ ls -la ~/.ssh/  
total 32  
drwx------  2 chuff chuff 4096 Jan  3 15:42 .  
drwxr-x--- 41 chuff chuff 4096 Jan  3 15:15 ..  
-rw-r--r--  1 chuff chuff 2590 Jan  3 16:43 id_rsa  
-rw-r--r--  1 chuff chuff  563 Jan  3 16:43 id_rsa.pub  
-rw-r--r--  1 chuff chuff  728 Aug  3 13:21 known_hosts  
-rw-r--r--  1 chuff chuff  506 Aug  3 13:21 known_hosts.old  
-rw-r--r--  1 chuff chuff 2590 Jan  3 15:17 my.key  
-rw-r--r--  1 chuff chuff  563 Jan  3 15:17 my.key.pub
```

All of the above is executed on my server.

When I try to run ssh-copy-id on my laptop I get the following:

```
chuff@osmc:~/.ssh$ ssh-copy-id -i /home/chuff/.ssh/id_rsa.pub chuff@192.168.0.3  
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/home/chuff/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': No such file
```

I can telnet into my server from my laptop so I know I can get into it:

```
chuff@osmc:~/.ssh$ telnet 192.168.0.3 22  
Trying 192.168.0.3...  
Connected to 192.168.0.3.  
Escape character is '^]'.  
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.5
```

And if I try to connect via ssh I get this:

```
chuff@osmc:~/.ssh$ ssh -vv chuff@192.138.0.3  
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023  
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config  
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files  
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *  
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.138.0.3 is address  
debug2: ssh_connect_direct  
debug1: Connecting to 192.138.0.3 [192.138.0.3] port 22.
```

and it goes no further.

This is absolutely doing my head in.

If anyone can help I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please use [code block]s to format the command output. Quote formatting (like used here) mix up the lines making it harder to read. That said (a) both actions - generating the key *and* copying it to the server are to be done from your laptop, instead of generating the key on the server and copying from your laptop (where there's nothing to copy). And b) also, you just seem to be unable to connect to your server from the laptop at all. Maybe check with your server's admin on how you can get the networking right for that.

Comment: It seems you're using Debian, is that correct? This site is unfortunately for Ubuntu only.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your replies. Muru, with regards to your points you are correct. I am connecting via SSH from my laptop to my Raspberry Pi which is running OSMC. I followed your suggestions from my laptop and it all worked perfectly but have been unable to do the same from my Pi. Artur, you are correct as the Pi is Debian based. This is clearly an issue limited to my Pi. I will take this question to the OSMC forum. Thanks for the help. It has further refined the problem.